# Twilio Flex dashboard, trigger webhook when sending sms

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

When sending sms message from twilio flex dashboard directly, there is no webhook triggered , just wondering if there is a way to force webhook trigger for outgoing sms messages from twilio flex dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe (Flex isn't my specialty, I'm afraid) that Flex uses Proxy to send messages. You could look into hooking into the [Proxy service webhooks](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/api/webhooks).

Alternatively, you could [create a Flex plugin](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/quickstart/getting-started-plugin) that triggers an HTTP request when a user sends an outbound message.